# Refactor: "Extract Method" error and unexpected outcome

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rope

I'm experiencing weird refactoring behavior.
With this line of code:

```
variable = 1 + 2 + 3
```

When I try to extract a variable, by highlighting "1 + 2", then right click -> choose "extract variable" option, i get this outcome:

```
newvariable74 = 1 + 2
a = newvariable74 2 + 3
```

I have other issues with refactoring. I get different results when testing the [rope examples from the docs](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/overview.rst#renaming-occurrences-in-strings-and-comments)

For example, this code:

```
def f():
    a_var = 1
    # INFO: I'm printing `a_var`
    print 'a_var = %s' % a_var
```

...after renaming 'a_var' to 'new_var', the new code should look like this:

```
def f():
    new_var = 1
    # INFO: I'm printing `new_var`
    print 'new_var = %s' % new_var
```

but instead, I get this:

```
def f():
new_var = 1
# INFO: I'm printing `a_var`
print ('a_var = %s' % new_var)
```

notice how the content of the string doesn't change.

Some info:

- I use Python 3.8.2 64-bit
- Visual Studio Code: 1.47.1
- Linux Mint 20
- Linux Kernel 5.4.0-40-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the refactoring function of vscode variables and methods is provided by Python extension, but its refactoring does not support renaming function.

For variable refactoring in vscode, you could try adding parentheses to it to make it recognized.

```
variable = (1 + 2) + 3
```

If you want to rename all 'a_var' to 'new_var' in vscode, you could try using `Ctrl+F2`.It will change all 'a_var' that appear in the current file.

When I use '`F2`', it only changes the *variables* in the current file, 'new'_ Var =% s' will not be recognized.

You can refer to:[Refactoring](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_refactoring)